# Ajax load image from json

Tags: jquery, json

I found an interresting tutorial and script about loading images with jQuery/ajax/json in the following link:

http://johnveldboom.com/posts/38/jquery-ajax-loading-display-images-or-text-until-script-is-finished

There is also a link to view a demo on jsfiddle in the beginning of the tutorial.

But i guess there is a missing part here to fully understand how this works, and that is the json code in the external file!? How could that look? I need to view an json example to fully understand this tutorial and script.

Anyone how can help me with this or proposals of better tutorials? There are very few tutorials about this.

Comment: Yes but what you need you need explanation?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit I need explanation and to view an fully working code example where I also can se how the json code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample script in the totorial loads data from github. As the JSON response is loaded from a free accessible server you can simply take the url of the endpoint, enter it in a browsers address bar and you are done.

Following your example the address is

```
https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom
```

and i get

```
{
  "login": "jveldboom",
  "id": 303202,
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/303202?",
  "gravatar_id": "adfc243d062a2b77e6c33b9117138793",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/jveldboom",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "John Veldboom",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "johnveldboom.com",
  "location": "Waynesboro, GA",
  "email": null,
  "hireable": true,
  "bio": "",
  "public_repos": 6,
  "public_gists": 14,
  "followers": 4,
  "following": 1,
  "created_at": "2010-06-11T23:12:47Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-03-28T20:58:39Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for json tutorials

the source of the working jsfiddle it uses jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by jveldboom</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#save').click(function () {
    // add loading image to div
    $('#loading').html('<img src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');

    // run ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom",
        success: function (d) {
            // replace div's content with returned data
            // $('#loading').html('<img src="'+d.avatar_url+'"><br>'+d.login);
            // setTimeout added to show loading
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#loading').html('<img src="' + d.avatar_url + '"><br>' + d.login);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <button id="save">Load User</button>
<div id="loading"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't need a list of the script, I was looking for an example how that json code could look like for this particularly script